# Creating OpenStack instances based on pre-defined inventory

Tags: ansible, openstack

I have Ansible script that creates OpenStack instances. Each istances has same configuration, the only differrence is `instance_name` and `instance_ip` (used as a floating IP assigned to this instance). To create a new instance I provided those variables in command-line.

```sh
ansible-playbook \
  -i inventory.yml \ 
  roles/common/tasks/openstack-create.yml \ 
  --extra-vars "instance_ip=106.120.137.228 instance_name=dc-cloud-test"
```

Now, I would like to create those instances based on the inventory:

- `instance_name` should be a host alias
- and `instance_ip` should be read from `ansible_host` variable.

How can I achieve that?

Here's my playboook:

```yaml
- name: Create new instance
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    instance_boot_vol: "{{ instance_name }}-boot-vol"
    instance_data_vol: "{{ instance_name }}-data-vol"
  tasks:
  - name: Launch instance
    openstack.cloud.server:
      state: present
      name: dc-cloud-test
      boot_volume: "{{ instance_boot_vol }}"
      volumes: "{{ instance_data_vol }}"
      terminate_volume: yes
      flavor: nlp.pda
      key_name: "{{ openstack_key_pair }}"
      security_groups: default
      floating_ips: "{{ instance_ip }}"
      validate_certs: no
```

Comment: You should check: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables and also: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Your inventory should look something like that:

```yaml
[mygroup]
dc-cloud-test ansible_host=127.0.0.1
```

Your playbook should look something like that:

```yaml
    name: Create new instance
      hosts: localhost
      vars:
        instance_boot_vol: "{{ inventory_hostname }}-boot-vol"
        instance_data_vol: "{{ inventory_hostname }}-data-vol"
      tasks:
      - name: Launch instance
        openstack.cloud.server:
          state: present
          name: dc-cloud-test
          boot_volume: "{{ instance_boot_vol }}"
          volumes: "{{ instance_data_vol }}"
          terminate_volume: yes
          flavor: nlp.pda
          key_name: "{{ openstack_key_pair }}"
          security_groups: default
          floating_ips: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

Comment: I would change the openstack cloud server name, to use the alias name * ONLY IF THE ALIAS NAME IS THE SAME AS THE SERVER NAME* i don't know what the exact outcome you want.

Comment: Sounds like I good directories. I started from this and ended with looping over hosts belonging to a selected hosts group:  ` - include_tasks: openstack-create.yml loop: "{{ groups['openstack'] }}"`